# Does a simple SQL query exist to getting all hierarchical tree with nodes like [id, parent id]?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The Internet has a lot of information and a lot of decisions but they are all different and not always clear. Some fit into 7 lines and some in more then 50. Does a simple solution exist?

Table `users` have a field `id` and `parent_id`. How do I can get all users, if I know that the depth of the tree is unknown and can be quite large?

Comment: i think you need a little more complicated output, like all child users when an id is provided or so.

Just for fetching all users, you don't have to keep these kind of tree structure table

Comment: That table structure may require recursive calls to operate - you might be better off operating [a nested set structure](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nested+set+sql) instead. That simplifies the reading of your tree at the cost of making inserts more expensive.